# How to resolve Eslint plugin ambiguity?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a eslint config which extends some others. Those packages depend on "@typescript/eslint-plugin" but they use different versions.

```
  extends: ['airbnb', 'airbnb-typescript', '@some-private-eslint-cfg'],
```

This results in Eslint being unable to start. It complains about ambiguity, it cannot determine which version to use.

The error:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.19.0

ESLint couldn't determine the plugin "@typescript-eslint" uniquely.

Please remove the "plugins" setting from either config or remove either plugin installation.
```

However, since I can't edit the configs of those packages I'm extending, I can't remove it from plugins[] and I can't uninstall it.

How to solve this? Ideally, I would like to add something to my top level .eslintrc to handle this. Is this possible?

Comment: you can see this as reference as well - https://eslint-kit.gitbook.io/eslint-kit/common-issues

short answer is that you will need to remove one of the plugins. In my case, `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` was conflicting with `eslint-config-react-app`, so I removed the first one to fix it.

Comment: same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when there are multiple versions of the plugin in question. ESLint not being able to resolve it "uniquely" means it found multiple (so, not "unique") versions.

This *is* resolved by upgrading to typescript-eslint@6. See [Parsing error: DeprecationError: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and can no longer be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996326/parsing-error-deprecationerror-originalkeywordkind-has-been-deprecated-since).

If you're seeing this error, it means that somewhere in your installed packages, an unexpected typescript-eslint version is floating around. Try:

- Bumping versions of all packages that mention ESLint and/or TypeScript to their latest version
- Clearing your `node_modules/` directory and re-installing
- Clearing whatever lockfile your package manager uses (`package-lock.json`, `pnpm-lock.yaml`, `yarn.lock`, etc.) and re-installing

If all else fails, you can set [`package.json` `overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) or an equivalent feature for your package manager of choice - to make sure all typescript-eslint packages mentioned in your lockfile are set to v6. But this really should not be necessary. Most of the time, this issue is from out of date packages.