# Parsing error: DeprecationError: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and can no longer be used

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

When upgrading an existing React project I'm getting the following error at line 0 of every .tsx file.

`Parsing error: DeprecationError: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and can no longer be used. Use 'identifierToKeywordKind(identifier)' instead.`

How can I diagnose and remove the error?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Having updated libs:

```
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
@typescript-eslint/parser
```

to versions 6.x resolved the problem.

See https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/7155#issuecomment-1692384149 for additional details.

Comment: How can I do this for CRA?

Comment: For CRA you would need to use NPM's overrides (or Yarn's resolutions) to override the nested dependency: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13286

Comment: additionally in Next.js I had to `rm -rf .next` to make it work

Comment: In my case, I also had to set @typescript-eslint/parser as the parser in .eslintrc.json. The config line would look like this: **'parser: @typescript-eslint/parser'**. See more info here: https://typescript-eslint.io/blog/announcing-typescript-eslint-v6

Answer (score 20):

It's fixed once I updated my eslint typescript packages.
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.x",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.x",

```
npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin --save-dev
npm install @typescript-eslint/parser --save-dev
```

[image: My code after fixed]

[image: Update package]

Comment: I already had `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` in place and `npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin --save-dev` failed due to a dependency conflict, but `npm install @typescript-eslint/parser --save-dev` worked and it fixed it for me  thanks!

Comment: Awesome fixed bro

Answer (score 11):

For me downgrading the versions of typescript and eslint worked.

typescript: 5.1.6
eslint: 8.47.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: only the typescript downgrade needed in my case

Comment: I needed to downgrade both TypeScript to `5.1.6` and Eslint to `8.47.0` to get my Next.js project building again.

Answer (score 7):

for me just restarting ESLint server in VSCode worked!

hit `ctrl + shift + p` => `Restart ESLint Server`

Answer (score 6):

For my Next.js app what worked for me was:

1. npm i @babel/eslint-parser
2. Adding the line "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser" to my .eslintrc.json

So my final eslintrc.json was looks like this:

```
{
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Wait! If you have TypeScript code, please don't do this! This will break many typescript-eslint rules. Different ESLint parsers create different AST shapes, and the Babel ESLint parser creates different ASTs than typescript-eslint's. And the Babel ESLint parser won't generate type information for typed lint rules. See https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/6814.

Answer (score 4):

For Next.js projects upgrading [eslint-config-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-next) solves the error

Comment: Not only this lib

Comment: Didn't work for my Next.js `13.4.19` project unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while using the ESLint extension in Visual Studio Code, and it was due to the absence of the .eslintrc file (ESLint configuration file). In my case, I could resolve the issue by either removing the extension or adding the .eslintrc file.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading `typescript` from `5.3.3` to `5.1.6` worked for me. Note I'm not being precise here - I didn't work out what the minimum downgrade should be, I'm just informing you that this specific version worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Installing newer versions of `@typescript-eslint` packages did not resolve this issue for me, because it installed them alongside the old versions.

The root of the issue is that `eslint-config-react-app` hasn't been updated in 2 years. It has dependencies on v5 of `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser`.

The only way I know of to override those dependencies (outside of updating the `eslint-config-react-app` package directly) is to use `resolutions` in `package.json`.

I added the following stanza to my package.json, re-ran the node_modules installation and fixed the error.

`package.json`

```
{
  ...,
  "resolutions": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.x",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.x"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today after attempting to upgrade to typescript 5 and reversing it, the message would not go away. ESLint was caching results, so simply re-saving the files it was complaining about made the issue go away.

Answer (score -1):

Adding "next/babel" to .eslintrc.json fixed the problem for me

Answer (score -2):

Same problem here, can't build my NextJS project.
The only solution for me was downgrading typescript (5.1.6) and eslint (8.47.0).

Answer (score -2):

For me I found that downgrading the @types/node version from 20.5.7 to 20.5.6 fixed the issue.

I have typescript 5.2.2 and eslint 8.48.0

Comment: Just tried this and still have the issue, are you sure you did not changed something else ?