# Parsing error: DeprecationError: 'originalKeywordKind'

Tags: typescript, next.js, eslint

This morning every single tsx file of my NextJS repository is throwing this error.

```
Parsing error: DeprecationError: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and can no longer be used. Use 'identifierToKeywordKind(identifier)' instead.eslint
```

I did not touch anything in the weekend and this just appeared out of nowhere. The build is not failing but every single .tsx file throws an error.

This is my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.6.2",
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.8.0",
    "@auth0/nextjs-auth0": "^1.9.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@mui/material": "5.10.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "formik-mui": "^5.0.0-alpha.0",
    "fp-ts": "^2.11.5",
    "graphql": "^16.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.2",
    "loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.64.0",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "chokidar-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.3.0",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
```

Did you encounter the same error or do you know how to sort this one out?

Comment: Looks like someone already had that issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996326/parsing-error-deprecationerror-originalkeywordkind-has-been-deprecated-since](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996326/parsing-error-deprecationerror-originalkeywordkind-has-been-deprecated-since).