# React: [eslint] Line 0: Parsing error: DeprecationError: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and can no longer be used

Tags: reactjs, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am trying to integrate TypeScript into my React project, created with CRA.
I keep having the following error:

```
Line 0:  Parsing error: DeprecationError: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and can no longer be used. Use 'identifierToKeywordKind(identifier)' instead
```

I have tried updating

```
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
@typescript-eslint/parser
```

to v6 as suggested in several places, but it didn't solve the issue.

Here's the partial package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.0.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.52.1",
    "sass-vars-to-js-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.18.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

This *is* resolved by upgrading to typescript-eslint@6. See [Parsing error: DeprecationError: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and can no longer be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996326/parsing-error-deprecationerror-originalkeywordkind-has-been-deprecated-since).

If you're still seeing this error, it means that somewhere in your installed packages, an older typescript-eslint version is floating around. Try:

- Bumping versions of all packages that mention ESLint and/or TypeScript
- Clearing your `node_modules/` directory and re-installing
- Clearing whatever lockfile your package manager uses (`package-lock.json`, `pnpm-lock.yaml`, `yarn.lock`, etc.) and re-installing

If all else fails, you can set [`package.json` `overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) or an equivalent feature for your package manager of choice - to make sure all typescript-eslint packages mentioned in your lockfile are set to v6. But this really should not be necessary. Most of the time, this issue is from out of date packages.

Comment: Yes, I see that I have 2 versions of typescript-eslint (6.18.0 and 5.5.0). But the 5.5.0 seems to be dependent of react-scripts package.

Comment: Basically I have "eslint-config-react-app#@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0" that depends on "eslint-config-react-app" (7.0.1), that in turn depends on "react-scripts" (5.0.1)

Comment: Yeah, react-scripts _should_ ideally update to the latest typescript-eslint version. But it looks like they're not going to any time soon. Which is a big part of why folks are moving away from create-react-app / react-scripts. If you want to stay on CRA then you'll need to use `overrides` or an equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But once I've created my app with CRA is it possible to get rid of it and use Vite for instance? Or it's just possible when creating a new project?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with your app once it's created, sure. You can manually swap out any configs, dependencies, scripts, etc. At the end of the day most apps are a handful of config files on top of a bunch of source code.

Answer (score 0):

After following @Josh's suggestion above, I found out that the issue for me was stemming from an outdated version of `dependency-cruiser`. Per their [release notes](https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser/releases/tag/v13.0.3):

> 6276288 chore(extract): makes 'require' detection with typescript >5.2.0 as well (#811)
> -> this fixes the DeprecationWarning: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and will no longer be usable after v5.2.0. Use 'identifierToKeywordKind(identifier)' instead. typescript/ tsc warning some of you might've been getting.

After upgrading from v13.0.2 to the latest version, this error went away. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for your answer. However, I don't use dependency-cruiser, so I don't think that is the issue in my case